# How can I store the accumulated value(integer) in React?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have an array of anecdotes and two buttons. One is to vote and the other is to randomly select the next anecdotes. When I click the vote button, the vote is seen as increasing numbers. However, the problem is that when I click on the next anecdotes, the vote remains instead of resetting back to the number zero for new anecdote.

I tried to store the vote numbers by first adding a new attribute **Vote** with an empty value "" to the array **anecdotes**, anecdotes.forEach(function (anecdote) { anecdote.Vote = "" }); and then pushing the increasing vote numbers to a new copy of an array **const copyAnecdotes = [...anecdotes]** but it didn't work. How can I make this work ?

App.js

```
import { useState } from 'react'

const inlineParagraph = {
  display: 'inline-flex',
  flexDirection: 'column',
}

const inlineButton = {
  display: 'flex',
  marginTop: '5px',
  gap: '10px',
}

const Button = (props) => {
  return (
    <div>
      <button onClick={props.handleClick}> {props.text} </button>
    </div>
  )
}

const App = () => {

  const handleClick2 = () => {
    setSelected(Math.floor(Math.random()*anecdotes.length))
  }

  const handleVote = () => {
    setVote(vote + 1) 
  }

  const anecdotes = [
    'If it hurts, do it more often.',
    'Adding manpower to a late software project makes it later!',
    'The first 90 percent of the code accounts for the first 10 percent of the development time...The remaining 10 percent of the code accounts for the other 90 percent of the development time.',
    'Any fool can write code that a computer can understand. Good programmers write code that humans can understand.',
    'Premature optimization is the root of all evil.',
    'Debugging is twice as hard as writing the code in the first place. Therefore, if you write the code as cleverly as possible, you are, by definition, not smart enough to debug it.',
    'Programming without an extremely heavy use of console.log is same as if a doctor would refuse to use x-rays or blood tests when diagnosing patients.',
    'The only way to go fast, is to go well.'
  ]
   
  const [selected, setSelected] = useState(0)
  const [vote, setVote] = useState(0)

  const copyAnecdotes = [...anecdotes]

  return (
    <div style={inlineParagraph}>
      { anecdotes[selected] }


      <div style={inlineButton} >
        <Button handleClick={handleClick2} text="next anecdotes" setSelected={setSelected} />
        <Button handleClick={handleVote} text="vote" setSelected={setSelected} /> {vote}
      </div>
    </div>
  )
}

export default App
```

Comment: You never set `vote` to `0`. Why do you expect it to be `0` again?

Comment: @Konrad I want the previous votes accumulated to be stored for one anecdote. setVote(0) will reset the vote back to zero but when I stumbled upon the same anecdote again, the vote should have remained and I can continue increasing the previously accumulated vote

Comment: @Konrad How can I accomplish this ? please help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First you need an array of votes:

```
const [votes, setVotes] = useState(() => Array(anecdotes.length).fill(0));
```

Then a function to add votes:

```
const handleVotes = () => {
  setVote((votes) =>
    votes.map((vote, index) => (index === selected ? vote + 1 : vote))
  );
};
```

And display correct votes:

```
{votes[selected]}
```

[image: Edit blissful-tamas-ilqqre]

Comment: Definitely the cleanest solution here.

Answer (score 1):

You should reset the vote inside your handleClick2 function

```
const handleClick2 = () => {
    setSelected(Math.floor(Math.random()*anecdotes.length));
    setVote(0); 
}
```

Comment: But what if I want the previous votes accumulated stored for one anecdote ? for now , using the code above, everything will reset back to zero. When I stumbled upon the same anecdote again, the vote should have remained and I can continue increasing the vote